# How to use roles in a Laravel package

Tags: laravel-5, package, roles

I'd like to have roles in a package I'm creating. What is the best way to do this?

Should I use an existing package (Entrust, Bouncer, etc.) or should I implement a roles feature with no dependency?

Using an existing package could end in a conflict if it's already installed in another version, or if another package is already used.

Implementing the feature with no dependency is like reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the best approch is probably to not define roles or implement authorization of any kind in the package and let the user define policies in their application.

Default policies may be provided and published with `artisan vendor:publish` command, if the user wants to.

Models should use Gate to check user's ability to view/create/delete/etc.